# Defining characteristics of mutable data structure objects

Tags: data-structures, dto, value-object

Assume we have *data structure objects* - some of them are DTOs and some of them are VOs. Also assume that Value Objects are immutable and Data Transfer Objects are immutable and readonly, then:

**How would you generally call/define mutable data structures?**

Note that they aren't entities either because they don't have identifiers. For example, it could be some event passed between ordered listeners which depend on information from previous listeners (like stopping propagation, etc.)

EDIT: I realize that objects are supposed to tie state and behavior - I'm not trying to separate them. If you think these objects should be DTOs or VOs or what I described are just *objects* then that's fine - this is still an answer to me. I'm interested in popular opinion - ultimately those programming rules are largely opinion based and shaped by politics. Maybe some will deem this question ill-suited for stack exchange as primarily opinion-based, but I think most of the answers here are just that.

Comment: Classes and namespaces are best called by domain, not by implemented patterns.

Comment: @slepic I would generally agree but it is easier done in domain part of code. What if what you are modeling is actual architecture/framework - is naming something `Message`/`MessageBus` calling by domain or implemented patterns?

Comment: I think the terminology here is highly confused. "Verbs" in natural language are not "objects" - they are actions (that is, they say something *about* the dynamics of objects). On the other hand, "mutable objects holding state" (and which have attached methods) *are* the quintessential object - both in natural language and in the OO paradigm. "Value objects" are not true objects at all - they are "data structures", "records", or similar. "Mutability" is an orthogonal issue concerned with referential correctness within a program.

Comment: @Steve After rereading my question I realized it may sound like this. I updated my question to clarify that I'm not trying to separate state and behavior. I also realize VOs are more like data structures. My question also stems from assumption that DTOs should be simple/just data structure and therefore have only public, readonly properties. And thus not mutable. And thus I asked about similar objects but mutable.

Comment: (Just to be clear, I'm not a downvoter btw.) My point is that real objects are inherently mutable, and OO objects are supposed to be mutable. The real question is what to call the *immutable* DTOs and VOs - I'd suggest traditional, descriptive terminology like "messages" or "structures". The word "object" has become like the word "thing" - the word means nothing at all, but is used in sentences when the meaning is implied by context. Many developers have taken to using the word to describe any possible programming artefact, and thus frequently saying nothing about what they actually mean.

Comment: @Steve I guess you are right. I definitely agree with you on the issue with semantic satiation of the word object - I would phrase it a little different though. I would say that Value Objects are just that - they are objects impersonating values/primitives (and one import thing about that is they return copy when mutated) and objects are objects. So are DTOs - they are objects. And immutable objects are different things. As you said the answer to my question would be something like `Structure`/`Record`. If you would convert it into the answer I would gladly accept it - if it won't get deleted.

Comment: And just to clarify why I'd choose that terminology. With a message, there is no natural assumption that it is mutable once sent beyond the scope of the creator - we do not put a letter in the postbox and expect to modify it later, and if the recipient has your letter, he does not expect that you updating your copy will change his copy. As for data structures, I would suggest not mixing mutable and immutable styles, so that there isn't a need to routinely distinguish both.

Comment: Perhaps you are overloading the word "object". There is the standard object of the OO paradigm which has both state and also attached methods which employ or manipulate that state. Then there is the object in modern programming languages, typically synonymous with what that language calls a "class" - and which may or may not contain either state or methods. This latter kind can include confounding cases, such as ostensibly stateless, method-only objects whose real role is as carriers for function pointers (which is their state)... (1/2)

Comment: ...(2/2) It can also include methodless "value objects". Mutable value objects could possibly have some programming purpose, as a *container* for values which can be passed around and the contents modified (thus the natural name for a mutable VO is a "container" or similar), but once value objects become immutable, I would argue this is a degenerate case of an object, in which all metaphor has been lost and the distinction with data structures has disappeared (the only remaining distinction is typically technical trivia).

Comment: I clarified this question once again - I think it is now more to the point and is not outdating answer.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you are asking. Is the question strictly about terminology, or does it have more to do with identifying what this kind of objects you describe actually are and what role do they play in the system? Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

You might not realize it but you're talking about entities.

Value objects are immutable because they are hashable. You can find them again based on their hash. Mutate them and that hash changes. Now you can't find it the same way. An entity is something you can find the same way even as it's value changes.

The idea of an entity is that it has an identity that isn't just it's state. I'm an entity because even as I get older or fatter, changing state, I'm still me. The typical way to find an entity is to give it an immutable Id field. However, you can simply hold a reference to it. Any scheme that holds on to the idea of something, regardless of its value, gives you an entity.

This should not be confused with constants. Pi might seem like a value object since it's value doesn't change but if your way of finding it remains the same, even if you switch to a universe where pi is 3, then pi is an entity not a value object.

Comment: I can hear the gears of these concepts grinding in my mind! A "value object" is synonymous with a data structure - the structure determines an arrangement or co-location of data, but the structure itself is abstract. On paper, a structure is neither the page nor the data - it's a specification for how things are arranged on the page, or how pages are arranged in the filing cabinet. An "entity" is synonymous with an object - or a page or a filing cabinet. It exists as a container separately from what it may contain, or how it contains things.

Comment: As for Pi, it seems to me to be obviously a value, and I'm not sure how it is characterised as an entity or an object (unless all numbers are characterised as entities, in which case the whole distinction between entities and values collapses anyway).

Comment: @steve you're thinking of pi as 3.14159. Think of pi as the circle constant. In some other universe that's 3. Changing the value doesn't stop it from being the circle constant if that's what it is in this other universe.

Comment: Treating reference as an entity's (kind of implicit) identifier is interesting view. I'm upvoting this answer for now.

Comment: I don't think I often employ "other universes" in my reasoning. What you're saying is that there is a conceptual indirection between "the circle constant" and what it's numerical value actually is. It's certainly possible to write a computer program in that fashion, but it's also possible not to. Typically, constants are not indirected at runtime, but substituted in place as values as compile time - few computer programs employing Pi will continue to work when sent to the next universe.

Comment: @Steve remember that computers don't care. What we're discussing is what these terms mean to us humans.

Comment: Incidentally, the older, fatter you continues to be treated as you, primarily because you are assumed to possess the same recollections and configurations of behaviour - the same "state" to that extent. Identity is always about state.

Comment: @steve [Don't be so sure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkrrVozZR2c&feature=youtu.be&t=101)

Comment: What the term means to a human mathematician maybe. Obviously, any formula expressed algebraically has indirection. But indirection is not synonymous with your definition of an entity, and thinking on my feet, I think I would distinguish between indirections which take the form of aliases for values ("constants"), and indirections which take the form of following references to resolve a value that will change dynamically during execution - a distinction I'm not sure exists explicitly in mathematics.

Comment: I'm not sure what the link establishes. A person giving directions doesn't know (or usually, care) about the identity of the person asking - they're performing a standard routine to the person who happens to be in front of them.

Comment: @Steve and thus, in this case, they don't care about state. They care about location. Indirection comes in many forms. A hash, an id, a reference, Some are impacted by state changes. Others are not. That's the difference with these terms.

Comment: The location is part of the state - not the intrinsic state of the lost stranger of course, but the state of the scenario involving them both. Alternatively, the intrinsic state of the stranger is that he recalls the beginning of the exchange of information. Perhaps to that degree the good samaritan does care about identity, but only in the pauce sense that he understands giving directions is a somewhat atomic operation, and the receiver must be present throughout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105804/discussion-between-candied-orange-and-steve).